# Run Fancybox after jQuery load

Tags: jquery, load, fancybox-2

I have an `index.html` file which loads content with jQuery's `load()` function, this `index.html` includes all the JS-files, the following too.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showNewContent() {
      $('#wrapper').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader);
    }
    function hideLoader() {
      $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    $('#menu li.load a').click(function() {
        // Change Content
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #all_content';
        $('#wrapper').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('body').append('<div id="load"></div>');
        $('#load').fadeIn(0);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#wrapper').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);
        }
    });

    ...some more code...

    $('.fancy').click(function() {
        $.fancybox.open([
             {
                 href : 'img/img1.jpg'
             }, {
                 href : 'img/img2.jpg'
             }, {
                 href : 'img/img3.jpg'
            }
        ], {
            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width: 75,
                    height: 50
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am loading the content from another file (news.html) to the index.html file. In this news.html file there is a link

```
<a class="fancy" href="javascript:;"><img src='img/img1.jpg' /></a>
```

but fancyboy does not work. How can I make it work?

I did not find a solution here for me until now. If someone has an answer or a link where I can find something usefull, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does "does not work" mean? do you get an error?
are you including the fancybox js inside the index.html?

Comment: No, I do not have an error, the fancybox overlay is just not loading.
It seems that tymeJV below gave a good advice, but it still is not loading to the end...

Answer (score 0):

You need event delegation since this anchor is being loaded in dynamically, bind the click event to an element that already exists:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fancy', function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
I included this new code:
`$(document).on('click', '.fancy', function() {
    $.fancybox.open([
  {
   href : 'img/img1.jpg'
  }, {
   href : 'img/img2.jpg'
  }, {
   href : 'img/img3.jpg'
  }
 ], {
  helpers : {
   thumbs : {
    width: 75,
    height: 50
   }
  }
 });
});`
but when I click on the .fancy-link the site flimmers for a millisecond as if the fancybox loads, but then it disappears again.

Comment: As I discribed it it seems to do something but in the end the fancybox is not loaded, just a short flimmer as if it is loading fancybox.

Comment: Hi, I found out why it behaved this way. Now everything is fine. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You better use an init-script that you call after loading content, is better than using document.ready().
When document.ready() is being called, the content is not present, it will we loaded afterwards, if this is what you mentioned.